# How to find rows with duplicate columns in a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with the data in the [EVE static dump](http://community.eveonline.com/community/fansites/toolkit/) and MS SQL Server Express.

The dump contains a table mapDenormalize, having columns named solarSystemID and typeID, both of which are ints (and neither of which is a key). I'm trying to find values of solarSystemID that appear more than once, with various combinations of typeID.

I have a query like

```
-- all systems that have a plasma or temperate planet
select distinct D.solarSystemID, D.typeID from mapDenormalize D 
  join invTypes T on D.typeID = T.typeID 
    where T.typeName in ('Planet (Plasma)', 'Planet (Temperate)') 
    order by solarSystemID
```

which returns 1 row for each solarSystemID that has a Plasma planet and 1 row for each with a Temperate planet. I am trying to figure out how to use this as a subquery to find solarSystemIDs that have *both* kinds of planets, but have come up empty-handed.

I started out thinking that I would do something like

```
select solarSystemID from ( the above query ) where count(solarSystemID) > 1
```

but that doesn't parse. What is the correct approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicate rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Comment: @Michael is correct, the answer at his link contains the key: naming the subquery with "AS" so the columns in the subquery can be named.

Answer (score 0):

```
select D.solarSystemID, count(D.solarSystemID) as counts
from mapDenormalize D 
     join invTypes T 
     on D.typeID = T.typeID 
where T.typeName in ('Planet (Plasma)', 'Planet (Temperate)')
group by D.solarSystemID
having count(D.solarSystemID) > 1;
```

[**<kbd>The sqlfiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/71372/1)

Answer (score -1):

Name the subquery with AS, so the columns in it can be used as arguments to COUNT and GROUP BY

```
-- all systems that have at least 1 each plasma and temperate planet
select distinct Foo.solarSystemID from 
    (select D.solarSystemID, D.typeID from mapDenormalize D join 
    invTypes T on D.typeID = T.typeID 
        where T.typeName in ('Planet (Plasma)', 'Planet (Temperate)')) 
    as Foo group by Foo.solarSystemID having COUNT(Foo.solarSystemID) > 1
```

thanks to @Michael for pointing out the relevant question.